# JavaScript syntax highlighter does not highlight template literals correctly

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, javascript

The `lang-js` highlighter does not appear to recognize [backticked strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) properly:

```js
let s = `a a a 'a a a' "a a a" a a ${true}`;  // not quite
let t = `a a a 'a a a ${true}'`;              // a little worse
let u = 'a a a \'a a a\' "a a a"';            // correct
let v = "a a a 'a a a' \"a a a\"";            // correct
let w = `a 'a a`; if (true) { }               // very not correct, but only if last line.
```

Currently renders as:

> [image]

A number of issues are shown above:

- Quoted strings inside template literals are mercilessly highlighted (even the placeholder expressions), but the text is not.
- Unmatched quotes inside template literals cause the remainder of the line to be highlighted, although this only seems to happen if it's on the very last line.

All text *except* placeholder expressions should be highlighted as a string when inside backticks.

Chrome 58, Windows.

Comment: Presumably you're aware of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work; do you think this is an SE problem rather than a prettify problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have no idea. I've [reported it there, too](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/492), thanks!